# How do I retrieve the Safe address book items via the SDK?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is there a way to retrieve the Safe address book entries via the SDK? I suppose it must be somewhere on the Safe class. Or maybe the Safe Service. Could be that this is not possible.

I researched the docs, didn't find anything in https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/safe-core-sdk